# How do I turn a "fat" library into a "non-fat" library?

Tags: c++, macos, compiler-construction

I'm trying to remove a duplicate object from a library with armv6 and armv7 architectures, i.e.,

> $ lipo -info libx.a
>   Architectures in the fat file:
>   libx.a are: armv6 armv7

As expected, "ar d" does not work directly so I used "lipo -extract" to split the library.  However, the resulting libraries are still 'fat' architecture.

> $ ar d libx-armv6.a offendingduplicate.o ar:
>   libx-armv6.a is a fat file (use
>   libtool(1) or lipo(1) and ar(1) on it)
>   ar: libx-armv6.a: Inappropriate file
>   type or format
>
> $ lipo -info x-armv6.a Architectures
>   in the fat file: libx.a are: armv6

How can I un-fattify the library?  (You can imagine the sorts of links that come up when you search for 'remove lipo fat file' in Google.  Help!!)

Comment: Why is this tagged linux ? I don't think there is support for universal binaries in linux

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I am not familiar with `lipo`, but from its [man page](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/lipo/), it looks like you should be able to do this:

```
lipo libx.a -thin armv6 -output libx-armv6.a
lipo libx.a -thin armv7 -output libx-armv7.a
```

Comment: Is there a way to achieve the same for the iOS binary on linux platform?